# Break out of loop in AWS SWF activity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I'm running permanent loop in SWF Activity. Say like a web crawler crawling a website www.example1.com. However, I don't want to wait until it finishes crawling, but at certain time I want to terminate the activity and switch it to craw website www.example2.com instead.

I have tried to use 'try-cancel', 'terminate', workflow by workflow-id. It seems like it just sends signal to SWF to indicate that the task is finished in the AWS console, but the Activity process on worker is still running.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When activity is cancelled a heartbeat call returns flag that indicates that. So your activity loop should include heartbeating code to support cancellation. See "activity heartbeat" section from "error handling" page of [AWS Flow Framework for Java
Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/errorhandling.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! Just to note that heartbeating should not be called too often, otherwise AWS will send Throttling Exception.